# How to update a value in hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a cart model. Each cart has a quantity which is a hash.
I render cart in edit.html.erb.

It looks like this: [image]

I want to add a possibility to edit the second column. It's the value of hash.
See comment in the next code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr class="head-of-table">
    <th>Продукт</th>
    <th>Количество</th>
    <th>Цена</th>
  </tr>
  <% current_user.cart.quantity.each do |k,v| %>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <%= k %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= v %>
        <%= text_field_tag v # here I want to put a field and a button for updating this hash %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <% i = Item.find_by(name: k) %>
        <%= i.price * v.to_f %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

UPD:

Cart controller:

```
class CartController < ApplicationController

  def edit
    unless current_user
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    else
      @items = current_user.cart.items
      @cart = current_user.cart
    end
  end

  def update
    @cart = current_user.cart

    @cart.update(cart_params)
  end

  def make_an_order
    @items = current_user.cart.items.all
    @cart = current_user.cart
    @cart.price = @cart.final_price(@items)
    @cart.quantity = @cart.correct_quantity(@items)
    @cart.save
    redirect_to new_order_path
  end

  private 

    def cart_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:price, :quantity)
    end

end
```

Cart model:

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to  :user
  has_many    :positions
  has_many    :items, through: :positions

  def final_price (items)
    self.price = 0
    items.each do |i|
      self.price += i.price if i.price
    end
    self.save
    return price
  end

  def correct_quantity(items)
    h = Hash.new(0)
    array = Array.new
    items.each do |i|
      array << i.name
    end
    array.each{|e| h[e] += 1}
    self.quantity = h
    self.save
    return h
  end

end
```

Schema:

```
create_table "carts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",               null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",               null: false
    t.float    "price",      default: 0.0
    t.hstore   "quantity",   default: {},  null: false
end
```

So again: Cart has a hash (hstore).
This hash I use for comfortable showing items in the cart (see correct_quantity). Key is an item name and value is a quantity. 
I want to add for users possibility to edit the number of items in the cart. Because of using hash I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Remember, the only way to persist data between requests is via the user's session, the GET or POST arguments, or a data store like a database or a file on disk. Manipulating variables in Ruby is only relevant **during the duration of the request** and then they're trashed. This isn't like an Android application where there's a persistent view and controller for as long as someone's using the application.

Comment: @tadman Your comment is so helpful (Actually not). I need something like a form for my edit and update methods in the cart controller. I don't know how to write such form. And of course this hash is stored in the database.

Comment: Honestly it sounds like you need to get a good reference book on Rails and dig into it some more because what you're asking for here doesn't really make any sense in the context of building web applications.

Comment: @DartNyan I guess you haven't read too many posts elsewhere. Just  a guess. If you *did* you would know that tadman registered pretty low, like zero, on the arrogant spectrum. So chill out.

Comment: @Drew If he doesn't know how to do it then why he wrote comment to me here? If thought stackoverflow was created to help people, not to rude them.

Comment: @DartNyan I have re-read his 2 comments twice may 3 times. His 2nd comment is a friendly advice comment. Knowing how he write comments, it is a friendly msg to a peer on what he suggests. I think you are inferring it wrong due to sensitivity

Comment: Maybe there's an understanding issue here, but I'm just trying to steer you towards resources that would help you both come to see how Rails views problems like this and how you can find a solution. Adding a field is only 50% of the solution, the other half is receiving the data and updating it in the database, and that's done through the controller. Since you haven't given any hints as to the schema, that's something you'll either have to tackle yourself, or explain in more detail so we can give more specific guidance.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear - you haven't given any indication of what you have tried and failed - my suggestion if you want to easily allow people to update their carts like most web sites do is that you should incorporate some javascript / AJAX on that sucker.  Include an edit button linked to the javascript call for the edit of that particular row